# Selenium IDE Regular Expression issue

Tags: regex, selenium, selenium-ide

I am having with an issue with a regular expression

```
storeLocation | CurrentUrl
storeEval     | re=/https://[.\w-]+/[.\w-]*\//;re.exec(${CurrentUrl})   |  jsHostName
```

it gives this error:

```
[error] Threw an exception: missing ) after argument list
```

Note:  I am noticing that Selenium IDE puts in extra slashes after I move the cursor to the text box that contains all the IDE commands I have entered.

```
storeEval     | re=/https://[.\\w-]+/[.\\w-]*\\//;re.exec(${CurrentUrl})  |  jsHostName
```

Comment: storeEval is on a separate line from storeLocation.. I'm not use to stackoverflow's editor.

Comment: I fixed that for you. For future reference, see: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 3):

`${CurrentUrl}` returns the value of a variable as literal text, but since you want to work with the variable in javascript, you need to access it through the `storedVars` array. Hence, if you change your script to the following it should work:

```
re=/…/; re.exec(storedVars["CurrentUrl"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is not valid: in JavaScript context (since, as you likely know, the argument to storeEval is a JavaScript expression) the general form of this shorthand constructor for a regular expression object is:

```
<variable> = / <your-regex> /
```

The important implication is that `<your-regex>` may **not** contain any virgules (/), unless you properly escape them with backslashes. You have done this for the final virgule in your expression but you have to do it for each of them, hence I have added three backslashes to get this:

```
re = /https:\/\/[.\w-]+\/[.\w-]*\//;
```

Note that you can even validate your regex right here on SO(!): Look at your initial code fragment and you will see that just `/https:/` is highlighted in burgundy; with my code fragment just above the entire right-hand-side is highlighted in burgundy.

This fix should get you farther; have not checked it in Selenium to see if it resolves your entire issue.